# TRUNCATE some ids without delete other values MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, truncate, sql-drop

I want to TRUNCATE some values but I don't want to delete anothers...

I have 3 ids, and the next id will be 14 or something like that... I want that the next id will be 4... How can I do this?

---

I have one solution but I like other more simple. I can export all the table, truncate it, and later import it. But it's a lot of work. :P

Comment: Sorry, I don't search very well... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the next `auto_increment` value after deleting your records with

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 4;
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1861/1)

Comment: how would this rename 14 to 4?

Comment: OP didn't ask to "rename" 14 to 4, he asked how he could make the next id be 4 instead of 14.

Comment: To rename it, you can rename it with PhpMyAdmin or...
UPDATE your_table SET your_row =  your_new_value WHERE  your_table.your_row =your_old_value
;)